# not able to display json data sent from server

Tags: json, reactjs

I am receiving data from server as json data but not a able to display it on the browser i am getting error as

> " Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {_id, Id, Name, Age}). If you meant to render a collection of
>   children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method
>   in student"

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Student extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      post:[]
    }
  };


componentDidMount(){
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/student')
  .then(data => this.setState({post:data}));
    }


  render(){
    return(
<div className="pre">

<h1>{this.state.post.data}</h1>
</div>
    );
  }
}
export default Student;
```

Comment: axios return response object which contain data property. use `data.data`

Comment: Can you log data in the axios .then function and include the result in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests that `this.state.post.data` is an object and hence you need to convert it to a string before  rendering. Use `JSON.stringify()`

Try

```
class Student extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      post:[]
    }
  };


componentDidMount(){
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/student')
  .then(data => this.setState({post:data}));
    }


  render(){
    return(
<div className="pre">

<h1>{JSON.stringify(this.state.post.data)}</h1>
</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()` convert whole `object` into a `string`, instead of using this, u can render the specific property of `object`. In ur case data object contains 4 keys `_id, Id, Name, Age,` so render it like this:

```
render(){
    return(
       <div className="pre">
          <h1>
              Name: {this.state.post.data.Name}
              <br/>
              Age: {this.state.post.data.Age}
              <br/>
              Id: {this.state.post.data.Id}
          </h1>
       </div>
    );
  }
```

By this way you will have a better control on each element, u can apply different styling, formats etc.